# EC2 instance passes health checks but no longer can SSH in

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-route53

I've had my website (an EC2 instance) running for a year now and everything was fine until this morning when I lost access to it and its associated database (an AWS RDS database instance). I can't access my website via the browser or SSH into either instance (the EC2 or RDS).

On the other hand, I can SSH into a different EC2 I have but oddly I can't access that website (a different domain name) from the browser either.

[All the global AWS monitors websites](http://status.aws.amazon.com/) and my own AWS dashboard monitors show everything is fine so I'm really stumped by this abruptly patchy access.

I'm using AWS Route53 for DNS but since this is also affecting my database, I don't think DNS is the problem.

Any thoughts on how to debug this?

p.s. I know this is not an billing issue b/c there have been no changes in billing.

Comment: Its not really a programming question either, which makes it more something for server fault. But if you do post it on there, make sure you include more information about your setup. I'm a bit confused as to where the problem might be.

Comment: Think you're right, i'll flag to request to migrate to server fault...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation before 6 months with one of my instances. But after a stop and start action I was able to SSH to that server. After log-in to the server I found a brute-force attack was there which made my instance unresponsive. So please Stop and Start your instance and then try to SSH it.